# Set up network to provide remote assistance

Tags: vpn, remote-access, vnc, teamviewer, remote-desktop

**Currently:**

On location **A** I've got 7 computers running Windows XP Professional SP3. I've got 2 of these running a free version of Teamviewer. *The rest have nothing and I can't access them from location B.*

On location **B** I've got a notebook running Windows 7, with Teamviewer.

**I need to be able to:**

- Access all computers in A from B (and not the other way around). *With Teamviewer, this is not happening.*
- Don't depend on someone from A actually being in the computer to access it. *With Teamviewer, this is OK.*
- Don't have to remember passwords. *With Teamviewer, this is OK.*

What options do I have? I thought about:

1. *Remote Desktop Connection* - I tried using it and the connection failed.
2. *VPN* - How do I add the computer in B to this network?
3. *Install Teamviewer in the remaining 5 computers* - This means that all computers from A will be able to "see" computer in B. Also, I should probably have to pay for it.
4. *Other software* - which?

Comment: LogMeIn Free???

Comment: There's the potential for this be a [good subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) question but as it stands right now it's close to being closed for being a [product recmmendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Can you edit it to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a free sign-up with LogMeIn.com on one of the computers at Site B and see how you like it. While you are at Site B, you can log in as a client from one of the other computers there locally and make sure the settings are working the way you like them (for example, there is a setting to require the local user to agree to be "viewed" .. you can make sure this is disabled, etc.)

You don't have to pay for it, although they will try to upsell you to Pro sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If this was me, I would:

1) Setup a VPN from Computer B to Site A. OpenVPN in Bridge mode would be my preferred option, but that may depend on what is available as an end-point at site A

2) Install a free VNC server on the computers at site A

Assuming there is some kind of firewall/NAT device at Site A, then VNC won't be accessible from the public internet, and once you are connected to the VPN, you're virtually part of Site A so using VNC is a piece of cake.